# Loading data from Azure Synapse spark pool to Synapse SQL dedicated pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I want write data from Synapse Spark pool into a Synapse SQL dedicated pool table using the SqlAnalyticsConnector

`import com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.utils.Constants`

`import org.apache.spark.sql.SqlAnalyticsConnector._`

`df.write.synapsesql("<DBName>.<Schema>.<TableName>", <TableType>)`

By default, the table that gets created has ROUND ROBIN distribution and CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX

Following are the questions:

1. Is there a way to create a HASH distributed table?
2. Is there a way to create CLUSTERED INDEX (instead of CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX)?
3. Is there a way to append data to an existing table?

Comment: That feature does not currently exist and would definitely be nice to have more control over the table distribution and indexing from the notebook.  You can vote for Append here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/506797/write-incremental-data-to-synapse-sql-from-synapse.html

Comment: I just use Synapse Pipeline and Stored Proc activity to change the table type using CTAS after the Notebook activity.

Comment: This connector has now been updated to include append, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export).